# Issue in renderpage when href clicked webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix

I have Created a website in webmatrix, Once we click on the Movie menu, the movies.cshtml page open in the Main Content RenderBody() _Layout.cshtml,
My requiredment is i have LastestMovies, OldMovies, NewMovies Href in the Movies .chstml page leftside div,
when i click, LastestMovies, it should open new LatestMovies.cshtml page in right side div,
whole process show run in the Movies.cshtml same as 
when i click, OldMovies, it should open new OldMovies.cshtml page in right side div,
whole process show run in the Movies.cshtml
How i can do this please assist me
Thanks in advance
Can we renderpage when we click the LasetMovies href?

_layout.cshtml

```
<body>
        <h1>JQuery Template Sample</h1>
        <div id="Menu">
           <ul>
        <li><a href="/Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Movies">Movies</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>

    <div id="Main">
            <div id="content">
            @RenderBody()
            </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Movies.Cshtml page

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="/Movies/LatestMovies">Latest Movies</a></li>
<li><a href="/Movies/OldMovies">OldMovies</a></li>
<li><a href="/Movies/New Movies">New Movies</a></li>
</Ul>
</div>
<div di="DisplayMovieArea">

</div>
```

Comment: show us the code... nobody knows what you are actually doing.

Comment: i have  added the code please suggest me..

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're saying. Do you mean to say that on the left of the page, you have whatever, and when you click something, you want its content to be displayed on the right of the page?

You could always use some JavaScript and an IFrame for that... Or you could just populate the right hand side DIV with new content when you capture the $(".whateverElement").click() in jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

in the href link seems u missed .chtml in your code .

make a correction like :  href="/Movies/LatestMovies.cshtml

Comment: You should be using something like this: `<a href="@Href("~/Movies/LatestMovies")" title="View latest movies">Latest Movies</a>`